# Retrieving data from parse but they are not available outside the query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to use the data I get from parse outside the `getInBackground()` function but the value of the fields is `null`

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Person");
            query.getInBackground(invitedBy.getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        // object will be your game score
//here the variables have an actual value
                        firstName = object.getString("firstName").toString();
                        lastName = object.getString("lastName").toString();  
                    } else {
                        // something went wrong
                    }
                }
            });
    //here the values for the firstName and lastName are null
        invitorName.setText(firstName + " " + lastName);
```

Any suggestions how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Most of the parse functions run asynchronously.  That means they get started, and your app carries on simultaneously.  In the posted code, at the point execution reaches setText, the getInBackground hasn't even begun.  But getInBackground takes a callback parameter to execute when it completes.  Do the setText within it.

Answer (score 0):

As @danh suggested in the comments, the parse functions (findInBackground, etc) run asynchronously. So before the firstName and lastName are assigned any values from the query result, the textView may set prior values of these variables. These are null as you say, maybe because they have not been assigned any value apriori.

You could call `invitorName.setText(firstName + " " + lastName);`inside the callback.

```
if (e == null) {
                        // object will be your game score
//here the variables have an actual value
                        firstName = object.getString("firstName").toString();
                        lastName = object.getString("lastName").toString();
                        invitorName.setText(firstName + " " + lastName);  
                }
```

or you can create a separate function say for ex.

```
private void setText(final ParseObject object){
// put your logic here
}
```

in the callback,

```
if (e == null) {
       setText(object);                     
 }
```

Hope this helps!